# Ms Access and SQL Server nvarchar(max) limited to 4000 characters

Tags: ms-access-2010, sql-server-2014, nvarchar, varcharmax

I have an Access 2010 application which has a table linked to SQL Server 2014. I have a table `Messages` which has a couple of columns, one of which is of type `nvarchar(max)`.

When trying to save a text with a length over 4000 characters to that column through MS Access form, it causes an error (runtime error 3146, ODBC--Call Failed).

However, when I insert a text of 4000+ characters into that column through T-SQL in SQL Server, it works without a problem. I have tried `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and still have the same issue.

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use? This is the current: [Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520026/3820271

Answer (score 0):

`varchar(X)` would do the trick. I'm not sure why would `varchar(max)` be limited to 4000 characters.