# Can I use UPDATE ... FROM in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getitng an error with this code:

```
UPDATE Intermedia
SET 
Remanente = c.[Resultado Remanente],
[Estado Cliente] = c.[Resultado Estado]
FROM Intermedia AS i
INNER JOIN [Cálculo_Remanentes_OT] AS c ON i.Concatenado1 = c.[CONCAT Estado Cliente + Error Code + Estado Basculación + Migrad];
```

Access says:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression: 'c.[Resultado
> Remanente],    [Estado Cliente] = c.[Resultado Estado] FROM Intermedia
> AS i INNER JOIN [Cálculo_Remanentes_OT] AS c ON i.Concatenado1 =
> c.[CONCAT Estado Cliente + Error Code + Estado Basculación + Migrad]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing other table details, this reorganized SQL *may* work:

```
UPDATE 
   Intermedia as i
   INNER JOIN [Cálculo_Remanentes_OT] AS c 
      ON i.Concatenado1 = c.[CONCAT Estado Cliente + Error Code + Estado Basculación + Migrad];
SET 
   i.Remanente = c.[Resultado Remanente],
   i.[Estado Cliente] = c.[Resultado Estado]
```

Comment: Ok, It works! thanks a lot!

But [Cálculo_Remanentes_OT] is a linked table, not in my db. [Intermedia] is a local table. Access says I can't do changes in a linked table but I'm not even trying to. So I had to convert [Cálculo_Remanentes_OT] into a local table in order to execute the query succesfully. However, no changes had been mades to [Cálculo_Remanentes_OT] so I can't figure out why it has to be a local table instead of a linked one. i even tried to remove the 'alias' for tables in the query code and it keeps working for local table but not for linked. Any clue? Thanks

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used Access, but what is the `linked table`, to an external spreadsheet or something? ... See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554800/cannot-delete-and-update-records-on-access-linked-table) might help with the link aspect.