# Changing datasource not working

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have a an Access form with a subform in datasheet mode with edit mode allowed. All tables are stored inside an SQL Server (2008R2) and I just added a new column (bit not null default 0)

The subform datasource span on 3 tables and is working just fine as it is. However, as soon as I add a new column, everytime I try to change data, I get this error :

[image: Error Message]

If I remove the column I just added, everything seems to work again.

Here is the datasource before

```
SELECT tblCommandeListe.Section, tblCommandeListe.Description, tblCommandeListe.[No item], tblCommandeListe.N°Commande, tblCommandeListe.Code, tblCommandeListe.Qte, tblCommandeListe.Dim, tblFournisseur.[Fournisseur-Nom], tblCommandeListe.Prix, tblCommandeListe.[Date de livraison], tblCommandeListe.[Cost Center], tblCommandeListe.Devise, tblCommandeListe.Complet, tblCommandeListe.[LB/Lin], tblCommandeListe.[Prix/lb], tblCommandeListe.Unite, tblCommandeListe.[Note 2], tblCo  mmandeListe.Ordre, tblProduits.[Produit-DescriptionFRA], tblProduits.[Produit-Prix], tblProduits.[Produit-Unite], tblProduits.[Produit-Fournisseur], tblProduits.[Produit-LB/Lin], tblProduits.[Produit-Prix/lb], tblProduits.[Produit-Long nom], tblProduits.[Produit-Devise], tblCommandeListe.Condition, tblCommandeListe.[Date création], tblCommandeListe.[Enlever liste à commander], tblCommandeListe.[Unite ing], tblProduits.[Produit-Unite_ing], tblCommandeListe.[Dim ing], tblCommandeListe.DescTmp, tblCommandeListe.[User mod], tblCommandeListe.[Qte req], tblCommandeListe.Annuler, IIf(IsNull([Qte req]),0,[Qte req])*IIf(IsNull([Prix]),0,[Prix])*IIf(IsNull([Dim]),1,[Dim])*IIf(IsNull([LB/Lin]) Or [LB/Lin]=0,1,[LB/Lin]) AS Total, tblCommandeListe.[Relaché pour achat], tblProduits.[Produit-Priorité], tblFournisseur.[Fournisseur-Nom]
FROM (tblCommandeListe 
LEFT JOIN tblProduits ON tblCommandeListe.Code = tblProduits.[Produit- Code]) 
LEFT JOIN tblFournisseur ON tblProduits.[Produit-Fournisseur] = tblFournisseur.Fournisseur_id
ORDER BY tblCommandeListe.Section, tblCommandeListe.Description;
```

and after I add the column

```
SELECT tblCommandeListe.Section, tblCommandeListe.Description, tblCommandeListe.[No item], tblCommandeListe.N°Commande, tblCommandeListe.Code, tblCommandeListe.Qte, tblCommandeListe.Dim, tblFournisseur.[Fournisseur-Nom], tblCommandeListe.Prix, tblCommandeListe.[Date de livraison], tblCommandeListe.[Cost Center], tblCommandeListe.Devise, tblCommandeListe.Complet, tblCommandeListe.[LB/Lin], tblCommandeListe.[Prix/lb], tblCommandeListe.Unite, tblCommandeListe.[Note 2], tblCommandeListe.Ordre, tblProduits.[Produit-DescriptionFRA], tblProduits.[Produit-Prix], tblProduits.[Produit-Unite], tblProduits.[Produit-Fournisseur], tblProduits.[Produit-LB/Lin], tblProduits.[Produit-Prix/lb], tblProduits.[Produit-Long nom], tblProduits.[Produit-Devise], tblCommandeListe.Condition, tblCommandeListe.[Date création], tblCommandeListe.[Enlever liste à commander], tblCommandeListe.[Unite ing], tblProduits.[Produit-Unite_ing], tblCommandeListe.[Dim ing], tblCommandeListe.DescTmp, tblCommandeListe.[User mod], tblCommandeListe.[Qte req], tblCommandeListe.Annuler, IIf(IsNull([Qte req]),0,[Qte req])*IIf(IsNull([Prix]),0,[Prix])*IIf(IsNull([Dim]),1,[Dim])*IIf(IsNull([LB/Lin]) Or [LB/Lin]=0,1,[LB/Lin]) AS Total, tblCommandeListe.[Relaché pour achat], tblProduits.[Produit-Priorité], tblFournisseur.[Fournisseur-Nom], tblCommandeListe.EstProduction 
FROM (tblCommandeListe 
LEFT JOIN tblProduits ON tblCommandeListe.Code = tblProduits.[Produit-  Code]) 
LEFT JOIN tblFournisseur ON tblProduits.[Produit-Fournisseur] = tblFournisseur.Fournisseur_id
ORDER BY tblCommandeListe.Section, tblCommandeListe.Description;
```

The only difference I see is the new column at the end. I tried with other columns and so far, it still works after, so the problem might be the column itself, but how can that be ?

EDIT : I just did a test and it seems I get the exact same message when I tried to edit it directly in the table in Access!

Comment: Can you post a translation of the error message?

Comment: Did you try un-bind and re-bind the table with the new column?  To be clear: in MS-Access, remove the connection from MS-Access to the the table that has been changed.  Then re-bind to that

Comment: @AHiggins: it's the `Write Conflict` message, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841539/bind-checkbox-with-a-bit-column-in-a-sql-server-linked-table

Comment: Actually your problem sounds a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841539/bind-checkbox-with-a-bit-column-in-a-sql-server-linked-table but since your new bit column is NOT NULL and has a default, probably not.