# MS Access with linked SQL Server - getting "This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it" message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, record, editing

I've got a SQL Server 2008 database. In this database I have 2 tables. We'll call them `TableA` and `TableB`. Let's say `TableA` is a list of companies and `TableB` is a list of people

I've got a view joining `TableB` to `TableA`, using a `LEFT JOIN` for `TableA` since I want everything from `TableB` on my Access Form
One (this Access form I list mainly everything from TableB, but some columns from TableA).
Some of these columns in TableA are `bit` columns, defined as `NOT NULL`.
If I'm looking at a record from `TableB` which has no record in `TableA` then when I modify it and try to move to a new record I get the following:

> *This record has been changed by another user since you started
>   editing it. If you save the record, you will overwrite the changes the
>   other user made. Copying the changes to the clipboard will let you
>   look at the values the other user entered, and then paste your changes
>   back in if you decide to make the changes.*

I need to be able to see these records which don't have the corresponding row within `TableB` and make changes to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try copying the changes to the clipboard as the error message suggests?

Comment: See this SO question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764508/nullable-bool-fields-in-ms-access-linked-tables