# Access ODBC Call Fail from linked table

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a SQL Server *view* set up, which performs correctly when opened inside SQL Server. It's got groupings and pivoting in the *view*. It's essentially a matrix of 1's and 0's with some unique identifiers.

However, when I try to open the *view* from Access using the below steps:

Access > External Data > Link to the data source... > Machine Data Source > 
Selecting the DSN > Selecting the View to be linked > Select Unique Record Identifier.

...I get the message: **ODBC--call failed**.

If I then try and open it, I get the expected amount of rows produced, but each field is populated with **#Name?**

Any clues to what might be causing this? The ODBC should be fine, as I can open up all other tables and *views* from the same database - just not this particular one.

Also, if I push the results of the view into a table, and try and open the table via Access, I still get call failed.

Comment: If you have Bit / Boolean columns in the SQL Server tables, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764508/nullable-bool-fields-in-ms-access-linked-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if there's a character limit on the column title. 3x of my columns had quite long titles - after reducing these I was able to resolve.

Comment: Interesting. How long were these column names (how many characters)?

Comment: 65 characters for the column name. But perhaps because it's using a linked table, that everything is fully qualified 'behind the scenes' and exceeding a limit? i.e. servername.dbo.dbname.tablename.65charactercolumnname